# Detecting update and deletion in Cosmos DB using CosmosDbTrigger in an Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I'm trying to work my way around DB notifications for document events in an Azure Function using `CosmosDBTrigger`.

I get notified for inserts and updates, however there is no notification for deletion. Is there any way to have it triggered or by design such type of events are not expected? (eg, event sourcing)

In case of an update, is there any way to check if it is an insert or an update? Maybe looking at the `ETag`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are no deletes in Cosmos DB change feed, so Functions aren't triggered either:

> The change feed includes inserts and update operations made to documents within the collection. You can capture deletes by setting a "soft-delete" flag within your documents in place of deletes

And there's no insert/update attribute available out-of-the-box, they suggest you do that on application level:

> There is no system property yet. However, you can add an attribute to the document, to do a soft update by updating the document attribute.

Both from quotes are from [Working with the change feed support in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed)

Comment: @KevDing Nope, I believe the answer still applies

Comment: They are currently working on putting deletes in the change feed, but as of now there is no ETA. If you want to keep track of the update the link is [Delete notifications for change feed](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/38873458-delete-notifications-for-change-feed)

Comment: @AndyDavies do you know if there is a new feedback page for this feature request? As your link has sadly died.

Comment: @Stanislas, hmm.. this looks like as good as we get, not good news... https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/1a462846-0e25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0858

Comment: As someone who wanted to react to deletions caused by the TTL feature, this makes me quite sad. I assume I'll now have to create my own TTL workflow using Logic Apps and ignore the native mechanism :(

Answer (score 0):

In June 2023, Cosmos DB has recently added support for an [All versions and deletes change feed mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/change-feed-modes?tabs=latest-version).

In contrast to the previous mode (Latest version change feed mode) we now get notifications of any and all changes to documents which includes deletions (including TTL-based document deletions). There are a few caveats including that it only works with your backup period, so you can no longer create a change feed processor from the start of your container, but it does provide more valuable information for ongoing reactivity.

It's not yet available as an Azure Functions Trigger, but I would assume that functionality is coming in the future.